# Expanding my Java program to send a alert message to other computers

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server, messaging

I've written a java intake program that send an PDF-formatted intake to a shared folder so that other people in the network can read it. However, there is not a way for the other people to know that an intake was sent unless someone tells them, so I want the program to send an alert message to the other computers telling them that an intake has been sent.

Now I've done some research into this and figured that TCP is the way to go since it's reliable. I also know that this is a one-to-many sending going on, so I assume that my Intake program will act as the server an the other computers will be the client, or should it be the other way around?

Now I assume that I have to create a client program that listens to the server and waits for it to send a message.

With that in mind, how do I:

- Create a client program that listens for the message continuously until the program is closed. I assume that I'll be using "while (true)" and sleep. If so, how long do I put the program to sleep?
- Make it as part of Windows service so that can load up when Windows start.

On the server end, how do I:

- Send messages to more than one computer, since TCP is not capable of multicasting or broadcasting. I assume an array/vector will play a part here.

Oh, this is a one-way communication. The client doesn't have to respond back to the server.

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer the question, but could you just email the person? Setting up a constantly listening service on someone's computer is normally not necessary.

Comment: Then the person would have to constantly check their email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, UDP is quite reliable (in fact, as reliable as the IP protocol itself). TCP simply ensures that the data was received which involved quite a lot of magic in the back end. Unless you absolutely need to be sure that other machines got the message, you could do it with UDP. Mind that I'm not saying “Don't use TCP”, I just want to make it straight that you should take UDP into consideration as well.

Anyway, yes, you can create a simple listening program. Here is an example of a client in Java that reads messages from the server. It overrides the run method of a Thread class:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        String messageFromServer = reader.readLine();
        while (messageFromServer != null) {
            // Do things with messageFromServer here                               
            // processor.processFromServer(messageFromServer);
        messageFromServer = reader.readLine(); // Blocks the loop, waits for message
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle your exception
    }
}
```

Amongst other things, my thread was set up as such:

```
public CommunicationThread(String hostname, int port, int timeout) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port);   
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(address, 2000); // 2000ms time out
    // You can use the writer to write messages back out to the server
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));         
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
}
```

Now, regards to server-side you can do something as follows:

1. Write a program to allow clients to contact, given that they know your address.
2. Accept the connections, and store the sockets in a list.
3. When you need to send out a message, traverse the list and send the data to everyone on it.

You can start listening on your server with

```
this.socket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

You could (or even should(?)) make it threaded so that you can accept clients while serving others. You can accept new clients with:

```
socket.accept(); // Blocks, waiting for someone to connect, returns open socket
```

Feel free to pass that to a whole new class which can deal with BufferedWriter (and maybe even BufferedReader if you want to read from clients as well). That class is where you would implement things such as writeToClient(message)
Consider the situation where you have a ClientConnection class that has writeToClient(String s) method and (Server server, Socket socket) and initialized ArrayList conList.
Here is how you would follow:
In a separate thread in Server, accept connections with

```
ClientConnection con = new ClientConnection(this, socket.accept());
conList.add(con);
```

Then, when you want to write to clients:

```
for (ClientConnection c : conList) {
    c.writeToClient("I'm sending you a message!");
}
```

I hope you get a vague idea of what you need to do. Read the Socket documentation, it's very useful. Also, as always with threaded applications, make sure you aren't doing things such as modifying a list while traversing it and avoid race conditions.

Good luck!

Comment: Cool, that looks almost like what I want to do. Now I'm not very familiar with threads, so what are race conditions?

Comment: Race conditions are things where the outcome can be different depending on which thread does something faster than the other working on the same data. Say you have two threads, one reads and print a variable's value and one increments the variable by one. If the variable is initialized to 0, depending on which thread executes first, the result printed will be different. Race conditions make debugging horrible and often can produce intermittent bugs. For java, look into `synchronized' keyword.  You can see an example of race condition here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing